# Equivalence of norms. How do I continue?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, equivalent-metrics

I have been working trying to solve a problem. It is about equivalence of norms. I am very close to finishing the problem. I have obtained a lower bound and I still need to obtain the upper bound. I have written the steps I am following in case someone could help me. First, here is the problem:

Check if for $x \in l^{2}$ norm

$
\|x\|_{1}=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n}\left|x_{n}\right| 
$

is equivalent to the standard norm in $l^{2}$.

Okey, and here it is my solution:

- For the lower bound, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\|x\|_1 &= \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n}\left|x_{n}\right| \\
&= \|x\| + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n}\left|x_{n}\right| \\
&\geq \|x\| 
\end{aligned}
$$

Because $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n}\left|x_{n}\right| \geq 0 $$.

So for the lower bound we have  $1 \|x\| \leq \|x\|_1 $.

- For the upper bound, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\|x\|_1^2 &= \left( \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^2 \right)^{1/2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^n |x_n|\right)^2\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^2 + \left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^n |x_n|\right)^2 + 2 \left( \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^2 \right)^{1/2}  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^n |x_n|\right) \\
&=\|x\|^2 + \left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^n |x_n|\right)^2 + 2 \|x\|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^n |x_n| \\
&\leq \|x\|^2 + \left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^n |x_n|\right)^2 + 2 \|x\| \\
&\leq  \|x\|^2 +  \left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^{2n} \right)   \left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^2  \right)+ 2 \|x\| \\
&\leq \|x\|^2 + \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{4}{9} \right)^{n} \right) \|x\|^2 + 2 \|x\| \\
&= \|x\|^2 + \left( \frac{\frac{4}{9}}{1-\frac{4}{9}} \right) \|x\|^2 + 2 \|x\| \\
&= \|x\|^2 + \frac{4}{5} \|x\|^2 + 2 \|x\| \\
&= \frac{9}{5} \|x\|^2 + 2 \|x\|\\
&\leq \frac{9}{5} \|x\|^2 + 2
\end{aligned}
$$

I do not know how to continue. In fact, there is one step where I have said that $2 \|x\| \leq 2$ and I do not know if it is correct. I have also used Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

What do you recommend me? I appreciate your help.

Comment: this question was asked yesterday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the upper bound, your first inequality is incorrect; you estimated
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n |x_n| \leq 1$$
and also, as you mentioned yourself, $2||x|| \leq 2$ does not hold.

What you can do instead is to simply use Cauchy-Schwarz on the second term of your new norm:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n |x_n| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2n} }\cdot \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2} = C||x||,$$
where $C = \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2n} }$ is finite. Hence
$$||x||\leq ||x||_1 \leq ||x|| + C||x|| = (C+1)||x||.$$

Comment: $$
\begin{aligned}
\|x\|_1^2 &= \left( \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^2 \right)^{1/2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^n |x_n|\right)^2\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^2 + \left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^n |x_n|\right)^2 + 2 \left( \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^2 \right)^{1/2}  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^n |x_n|\right) \\
&=\|x\|^2 + \left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^n |x_n|\right)^2 + 2 \|x\|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^n |x_n| \end{aligned} $$

Comment: $$
\begin{aligned}
&\leq \|x\|^2 + \left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^n |x_n|\right)^2 + 2 \|x\| \left( \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^{2n}}     \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^2} \right) \\
&=\|x\|^2 + \left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^{n} |x_n|\right)^2 + 2 \|x\| \left( \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^{2n}}  \|x\| \right) \end{aligned} $$

Comment: $$ \begin{aligned} &=\|x\|^2 + \left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^{n} |x_n|\right)^2 + 2 \|x\|^{2} \left( \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^{2n}}\right) \\
&\leq  \|x\|^2 +  \left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^{2n} \right)   \left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^2  \right)+ 2 \|x\|^{2} \left( \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^{2n}}\right) \end{aligned} $$

Comment: $$ \begin{aligned} &\leq \|x\|^2 + \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{4}{9} \right)^{n} \right) \|x\|^2 + 2 \|x\|^{2} \left( \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{4}{9} \right)^{n}}\right) \\
&=\|x\|^2 + \left( \frac{\frac{4}{9}}{1-\frac{4}{9}} \right) \|x\|^2 + 2 \|x\|^{2}  \sqrt{\left( \frac{\frac{4}{9}}{1-\frac{4}{9}} \right)} \end{aligned} $$

Comment: $$ \begin{aligned} &=\|x\|^2 + \frac{4}{5} \|x\|^2 + 2 \|x\|^2 \sqrt{\frac{4}{5}}\\
&= \frac{9+4\sqrt{5}}{5} \|x\|^2
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Then,

$$
\begin{aligned}
    \|x\|_1 &= \sqrt{\frac{9+4\sqrt{5}}{5} \|x\|^2} \\
    &= \left( \sqrt{\frac{9+4\sqrt{5}}{5}} \right)  \|x\| \\
    &\leq \left( \sqrt{\frac{9+12}{5}} \right)  \|x\| \\
    &= \left( \sqrt{\frac{21}{5}} \right)  \|x\| \end{aligned} $$

Comment: $$ \begin{aligned}  &\leq \left( \sqrt{\frac{25}{5}} \right)  \|x\| \\
    &= \frac{\sqrt{25}}{\sqrt{5}} \|x\| \\
    &= \frac{5}{\sqrt{5}} \|x\| \\
    &\leq \frac{5}{\sqrt{4}} \|x\| \\
    &= \frac{5}{2} \|x\| \\
    &\leq 5 \|x\|
\end{aligned} $$

Comment: So, we have $$ \|x\|_1 \leq 5 \|x\|$$.

Comment: Is it correct, now?

Comment: Yes, it is in principle correct. But it is a bit overkill; you can apply the estimate directly to $||x||_1$ instead of going through $||x||_1^2$.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I've just realised. Thank you very very very much